# Android Studio - datos no cargan en recyclerview

Tags: android

Estoy creando una aplicación donde la página principal está dividida en 2 tabs. Quiero mostrar los datos de un `JSON`, he probado en otro proyecto (poniendo todo en el main, sin tabs ni en fragmentos), y muestra los datos correctamente. El problema viene cuando intento hacer lo mismo en un fragmento.

No veo el problema por ningún lado, he consultado y mirado por diferentes sitios, pero sigo sin encontrar el error, al lanzar la aplicación el tab donde debería de aparecer la información se muestra vacío.

También hago uso de un `ProgressDialog` el cual no se muestra en ningún momento.

El `Log` muestra los nombres e imágenes del `JSON` correctamente, así que el error creo que es a la hora de intentar mostrarlos.

SurvisFragment:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_personajes_survis, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(SurvisViewModel.class);
        // TODO: Use the ViewModel

        configView();
    }

    private void configView()
    {
        initializeComponents();
        getSurvis("https://api.npoint.io/840b16c025f4b9eaa1f0");
    }

    private void initializeComponents()
    {
        recyclerView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewPersonajes);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(mContext, 3));
    }

    private void getSurvis(String url)
    {
        pd = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        pd.setMessage("Cargando personajes...");
        pd.show();

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response)
            {
                pd.dismiss();

                try
                {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("personajes");
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject object1 = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        if (object1.getString("Tipo").equals("Superviviente"))
                        {
                            data.add(
                                    new Personaje(
                                            object1.getString("Nombre"),
                                            object1.getString("Imagen")
                                    )
                            );

                            Log.e("PERSONAJES ", data.get(i).getNombre() + " - " + data.get(i).getImagen());

                        }
                    }

                    setPersonajes(data);

                } catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
            {
                pd.dismiss();
                Log.e("ERROR", "Error occurred " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });

        Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext).add(request);

    }

    private void setPersonajes(ArrayList<Personaje> data)
    {
        Log.i("ELEMENTOS", "Elementos a cargar " + data.size());
        personajesAdapter = new PersonajesAdapter(mContext, data);
        personajesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(personajesAdapter);
    }
```

PersonajesAdapter:

```
public class PersonajesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PersonajesAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    Context context;
    ArrayList<Personaje> data;

    public PersonajesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Personaje> data)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.fragment_personajes, null));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        Glide.with(context).asBitmap().load(data.get(position).getImagen()).into(holder.image);

        holder.name.setText(data.get(position).getNombre());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return data.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        ImageView image;
        TextView name;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        }
    }

    public Context getContext()
    {
        return context;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public ArrayList<Personaje> getData()
    {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<Personaje> data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
```

Comment: Hola, que mensaje de error se muestra en el LogCat?

Comment: @Jorgesys Ningún error, parece ser que recibe los datos correctamente pero luego el fragmento no carga los datos solo uno que hay de ejemplo.

Comment: Cambia lo que sugiero en mi respuesta y después dentro del método :  private void setPersonajes(ArrayList<Personaje> data) {   en su primera linea agrega : Log.i("ELEMENTOS", "Elementos a cargar " + data.size();   y comenta cuantos elementos se tratan de cargar

Comment: @Jorgesys El log del error no muestra nada, el de los elementos muestra "5".

Comment: Ok @mimoco  entonces si se obtienen datos al realizar la petición, permiteme revisar!

Comment: Prueba quitando la linea  personajesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); o colocala despues de agregarle el adaptador a tu recycler

Comment: @JoseAntonioDominguezGarcia Nada, sigue igual.

Comment: @mimoco4334 revisa mi respuesta, lo que comenta con respecto a el método setPersonajes().

Answer (score 0):

Esto puede generar error :

```
Log.e("ERROR", "Error occurred ", error);
```

debes cambiarlo a :

```
Log.e("ERROR", "Error occurred " + error.getMessage());
```

Configura el adapter y posteriormente usa `notifyDataSetChanged()`:

```
  private void setPersonajes(ArrayList<Personaje> data)
    {
        Log.i("ELEMENTOS", "Elementos a cargar " + data.size());
        personajesAdapter = new PersonajesAdapter(mContext, data);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(personajesAdapter);
        personajesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Pero el `setData()` que esta en `PersonajesAdapter` no se utiliza en el `SurvisFragment`. Además haciendo el cambio de arriba todo sigue igual.

Comment: solo cambia lo que sugiero para setPersonajes() y comenta que resultado tienes

Comment: El mismo resultado que antes. No se si quieres que te pase el proyecto o algo, ya que puede que mis comentarios sean poco precisos.

Comment: ok @mimoco4334 esta bien

Comment: igual compárteme tu proyecto me parece interesante esta problemática que tienes

Comment: @JoseAntonioDominguezGarcia Por donde lo puedo compartir?

Comment: puedes publicarlo en gihub por favor y pasar la liga déjalo publico para que todos podamos bajarlo y ya solo tu te encargas de ver las revisiones